Search products (documents) based on their ratings using mongoose
I was creating a full stack e-commerce website, when i came across this problem. I wanted to add a search filtering based on reviews star. The client sends query and minRatings  to the server and the API sends a query to the mongodb database searching for product which matches the query and the review stars should be  greater or equal to minRating.
Here's what I tried but this didn't work:
The query is written using Mongoose
const products = await Product.find({
        $or: [
          { name: { $regex: query, $options: "i" } },
          { productType: { $regex: query, $options: "i" } },
        ],
        stars: { $gte: parseFloat(minRatings), $lte:5 },
      }).populate("reviews");


Hope you understood my problem and can help me with finding the solution.

Make sure that the value of minRatings is string,if  parseFloat can't convert value it returns NaN.

What didn't work? Was products an empty array, were the wrong products retured, did it not populate, did it throw an error etc etc? Share a sample document you expect the query to match.
